# Connecting to Sphinx using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sphinx

I am trying to connect to Sphinx with PDO, and it isn't working, I am getting this error:
`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] Server sent charset unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers`

Here is how I am connecting:

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=xxxxxx;port=9306;", "", "");
```

I used to be doing it with normal mysql and that used to work, but now it isn't working for some reason.

This used to work (now it doesn't and it doesn't even give an error):

```
$sql = mysql_connect("xxxxxx:9306", "", "");
```

Comment: `Please, report to the developers` did you do that? (To get an error from `mysql_connect` you need `echo mysql_error();`)

Comment: Try: `$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=xxxxxx;port=9306;charset=utf-8", "", "");`

Comment: mysql functions don't spit out errors. they return a boolean false, and you have to test for that and then call mysql_error(). ditto with PDO. by default it doesn't complain and returns boolean false. if you awnt it to complain, test the values, or switch it to throwing exceptions.

Comment: charset didn't do anything, and I added `or die` after `mysql_connect` with `mysql_error` in it, and it dies but no error is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I fixed it.

What I did was downgrade php from `5.4.11` to `5.4.3`